# Implement slicer in SSRS with cascading parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to implement slicer in SSRS with cascading parameters using AdventureWorks2012 (http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/165399).
    There is three datasets: one(SalesbyCategory) for report, others for parameters.

Here is the query:
SalesbyCategory:

```
SELECT        PC.Name AS Category, PSC.Name AS Subcategory, P.Name AS Product
FROM            Production.Product AS P INNER JOIN
                         Production.ProductSubcategory AS PSC ON P.ProductSubcategoryID = PSC.ProductSubcategoryID INNER JOIN
                         Production.ProductCategory AS PC ON PC.ProductCategoryID = PSC.ProductCategoryID
WHERE        (PC.Name IN (@Category)) AND (PSC.Name IN (@Subcategory))
```

CategoryValues:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name AS Category
FROM            Production.ProductCategory
```

SubcategoryValues:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PSC.Name AS Subcategory
FROM            Production.ProductSubcategory AS PSC INNER JOIN
                         Production.ProductCategory AS PC ON PC.ProductCategoryID = PSC.ProductCategoryID
WHERE        (PC.Name IN (@Category))
```

function for inverse parameter:

```
Function parameterInverse(ByVal paramsArray As String(), ByVal parameter As String) As String()
    For i As Integer = 0 To paramsArray.Length - 1
        If paramsArray(i).Equals(parameter) Then                    
            paramsArray(i) = paramsArray(paramsArray.Length - 1)
            ReDim Preserve paramsArray(paramsArray.Length - 2)
            Exit For
        ElseIf i = paramsArray.Length - 1 Then                      
            ReDim Preserve paramsArray(paramsArray.Length)
            paramsArray(paramsArray.Length - 1) = parameter
        End If
    Next
    Return paramsArray
End Function
```

textbox action:
Category

```
=Code.parameterInverse(Split(Join(Parameters!Category.Value,","),","),Fields!Category.Value)

Subcategory = [@Subcategory]
```

expression to show if parameter selected:

```
=iif(Join(Parameters!Subcategory.Value,",").Contains(Fields!Subcategory.Value),"Turquoise","LightGrey")
```

When I click the Category textbox the error occurred

> none subcategory parameter passed

[image]

Why? Or should I change my thoughts?

Comment: Im not sure I understand the issue, can you explain it further? When you click an item in your subcategory and View Report, you receive an error?

Can you post the full error?

Comment: The code is right, the error is because the data(such as "Michael, Jackson") contains ",", when I split it use ",", it returns data("Michael" and "Jackson") that doesn't exist in dataSet.

Comment: Ahhh. If you are trying to split data with a custom value such as a comma, you need to use the + symbol, John + , + Smith. Unsure if that syntax is 100% but try that

Comment: I just use another symbol to split it, the issue has been solved. Thanks.